# SQLAlchemy Event Listens For "Before_Update" not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I use the *before_update* event listener, I'm getting the same output as the *after_update* event listener. I can't find out how to get the before_update event listener to record the data **before** the update is made to the appts_db table in my database.

I'm using the log_db table to store the changes made to appts_db. Here is my code:

**app.py**:

```py
class appts_db(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    carrier = db.Column(db.String(100))
    pickup_date = db.Column(db.String(10))
    log_id = db.relationship("log_db", backref="appt", lazy=True)

@event.listens_for(appts_db, "before_update")
def update_log_old(mapper, connection, target):
    po = log_db.__table__
    connection.execute (po.insert().values(appt_id=target.id, action='Updated - Old'))

@event.listens_for(appts_db, "after_update")
def update_log_new(mapper, connection, target):
    po = log_db.__table__
    connection.execute (po.insert().values(appt_id=target.id, action='Updated - New'))

class log_db(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    appt_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('appts_db.id'))
    modified_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    action = db.Column(db.String(7))
```

**log.html**:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Carrier</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Volume [gallons]</th>
        <th>Pickup Date [YYYY-MM-DD]</th>
        <th>Pickup Time [24-hr]</th>
        <th>Date Modified</th>
    </tr>
        {% for item in log %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.action }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.appt.carrier }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.appt.material }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.appt.volume }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.appt.pickup_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.appt.pickup_time }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.modified_on.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what data is meant to be different? Why should `before_update` give different results than `after_update`? From what you've shown all you're inserting in the log table is an ID value, static text and a datetime.

Comment: I made some edits to the question above. Let's say I have an appointment for carrier X to pickup a shipment on 2022/10/05, but the appointment gets rescheduled and the new pickup date is 2022/10/10. When I make this change to the date, I want the log_db table to record both appointments so I can see what change was made.

Comment: log_db will only contain the datetime and static text, but my html page will pull the other related data from my appts_db table (such as material, volume, pickup time, etc.).